# Mysql - sum time difference and group per hour

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, sum, aggregate-functions

I've ask recently question about grouping data per hour, but I will try to extend and explain more.

Currently I've managed to organized the structure like this:

```
 ChangeDate | ChangeTime | timediff |
+------------+------------+----------+
| 2020-10-07 | 19:51:26   |       46 |
| 2020-10-07 | 19:53:13   |       48 |
| 2020-10-07 | 19:54:20   |       21 |
| 2020-10-07 | 19:54:56   |      105 |
| 2020-10-07 | 20:13:53   |      209 |
| 2020-10-07 | 20:52:28   |       45 |
| 2020-10-07 | 20:53:43   |      210 |
| 2020-10-07 | 20:56:08   |      258 |
| 2020-10-07 | 20:59:43   |       13 |
```

The desire result is to group the data per HOUR of ChangeTime column and SUM timediff which is already done(those are seconds)

So the new table structure would looks like this:

```
| ChangeDate | ChangeTime | timediff |
+------------+------------+----------+
| 2020-10-07 | 19:51:26 or 19-20 if possible   |       48 + 46 + 21 + 105 |
| 2020-10-07 | 20:13:53 or 20-21   |      209 + 45 + 210 + 258 + 13 |
```

Second column it's optiona XX-YY format for example 19-20, cuz there can stay any particular value from that interval, again for this example 19:51:26...
Seconds also can stay, jus i need the sum i will convert them to minutes:seconds format...

This is so far what I've tried:

```
select DISTINCT MAX(t.ChangeDate) ChangeDate, MAX(t.ChangeTime) ChangeTime , t.timediff
FROM
(
select DISTINCT ChangeDate, HOUR(ChangeTime) ChangeTime, SUM(TimeDiff(CurrentTime,ChangeTime)) as timediff
from pins 
where serial="6381872047252543"
and CurrentDate >= '2020-10-07' and CurrentDate <= '2020-10-08'
group by ChangeDate, ChangeTime
) t
group by t.timediff
order by ChangeDate, ChangeTime asc
```

Br,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `hour()`:

```
select changedate, hour(changetime) changehour, 
    sum(timediff(currenttime,changetime)) as sum_timediff
from pins
group by changedate, changehour
```

Comment: Still getting multiple rows... i can't found way how to eliminate... HOUR is ok to convert to single number, but still i see multiple values... i'm not sure how to sum one more time and compress to one row... for example 2020-10-07 | 19h | 30s

Comment: @ИгорТашевски: this is guaranteed to generate one row per `changedate` and hour. Are you sure that you are running the query exactly as provided?

Comment: @ИгорТашевски: hmmm... your query is much different from the one I provided. The `where` clause is a mess (many conditions on the same column, some might contradict another). `DISTINCT` is not necessary at all when there is `GROUP BY`. And I don't see the point for the outer query with `MAX()`. An important thing is to give a different alias to `hour(changetime)` (I used `changehour`), otherwise it is ambiguous... Please try my query first, and see what it returns.

Comment: Yes i know is mess because od dev env... some unclean data etc... i see that your query make everything the same as mine, of course still i need mess where clause, but i can't still sum the timediff and in same time to have only one row:

| 2020-10-07 |         19 |           46 |
| 2020-10-07 |         19 |           48 |
| 2020-10-07 |         19 |           21 |
| 2020-10-07 |         19 |          105 |

Comment: @ИгорТашевски: again: my query cannot generate two rows with the same date and hour. That's what the `group by` clause guarantees. Here is an example built with the sample data you provided: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=406fd8c7448edc4d4c94a1505a110673

Comment: wow... changetime alias was making problems all the time... i replace all lowercase as your now is ok... thank you very much...